# Can you generate a todo.txt file from \todo commands with Doxygen?

Tags: language-agnostic, documentation, doxygen, todo

```
/// \todo Loop must be rewritten   
...
/// \todo Delete this loop
```

Can Doxygen generate a todo.txt file containing these comments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any way to do this directly, but it does generate a todo list; see [Adonthell's](http://adonthell.berlios.de/api/todo.html), for example. You could munge this into a text file if you really wanted...